I designed a face recognition attendance system but I am continuously getting the error "module cv2.face has no attribute LBPHFaceRecognizer_create
I am working in va code and  getting this error of cv2.face has no attribute ALBPHFacerecognizer_create.
What should I do? I tried my best gone through many YouTube videos tried every possible solution.
My protect is not showing the labelled image of already registered candidates due to the error

You have a typo. It is LBPHFacerecognizer_create and not ALBPHFacerecognizer_create, remove the A in the head of the function name.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

in question (not in comments) you should show code which makes this problem .

Try the following (and don't forget to correct the typo mentioned by @Ze'ev Ben-Tsvi):
import cv2.face
...
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer.create()

